# Several Figure+Figcaption on one line

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-material

In a dialog i want to display several download links with a caption on the same line :

```
<md-dialog-content>
        <div align="center" id="download">

            <a ng-href="https://community.site.com/it/urbsi/SiteGenen/{{currentCartography}}.pdf"
               download>
                <figure>
                <img src="style/images/pdf-icon.png" alt="Download PDF" width="15%" height="15%">
                    <figcaption>English PDF</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
            <a ng-href="https://community.site.com/it/urbsi/SiteGenen/{{currentCartography}}.pdf"
               download>
                <figure>
                    <img src="style/images/pdf-icon.png" alt="Download PDF" width="15%" height="15%">
                    <figcaption>French PDF</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a> 
            <a ng-href="https://community.site.com/it/urbsi/cartographies/{{currentCartography}}.vsd"
               download>
                <img src="style/images/vsd-icon.png" alt="Download VSD" width="15%" height="15%">
            </a>   
            <a ng-href="https://community.site.com/it/urbsi/SiteGenen/{{currentCartography}}_FS.png"
               download>
                <figure>
                <img src="style/images/png-icon.png" alt="Download PNG" width="15%" height="15%">
                <figcaption>English PNG</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
            <a ng-href="https://community.site.com/it/urbsi/SiteGenen/{{currentCartography}}_FS.png"
               download>
                <figure>
                    <img src="style/images/png-icon.png" alt="Download PNG" width="15%" height="15%">
                    <figcaption>French PNG</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
```

But my links are displayed on different lines. I tried `display: inline;`but no luck.

Which gives this instead of a one line dialog :
[image]

Comment: use `layout="row"` inside your div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `layout="row"` inside your div tag.

```
<md-dialog-content>
    <div align="center" id="download" layout="row">
        // your anchor tag
    </div>
</md-dialog-content>
```

**note**: as you uses `<md-dialog-content>` its means you are using `angular-material-design`